# Table not filtering

Tags: java, filter

I want the filter to keep all the values, instead of overlapping. What am I doing wrong? I want the filter to keep all of `exp.substring(11,19)` and not overlap

```
ArrayList<RowFilter<Object,Object>> arrLstColorFilters = new ArrayList<RowFilter<Object,Object>>();

if (time3[i].after(time1) && time3[i].before(time2)) {
    String exp = time3[i].getTime().toString();
    please.add(exp.substring(11, 19));
    RowFilter<Object,Object> blueFilter = RowFilter.regexFilter(exp.substring(11, 19),3);
    arrLstColorFilters.add(blueFilter);
}
sorter.setRowFilter(RowFilter.andFilter(arrLstColorFilters));
```

exp contains time formats: "09:19:19" Every value in arrLstColorFilters is not being displayed

Comment: I reformatted your code so I wouldn't have to scroll off the screen.  It just plain sucked (no offense).

Comment: Many of your variable contains 'filter', which one is the problem ? What is `RowFilter` ? You need to provide the code

Comment: Now onto your question, you have so many unexplained variables that this is inevitably going to close.  What is the overall goal of this code? Explain what all of the variables are as you have **no** explanation on what these are supposed to do.  What is the final output you are seeking? Give us more!

Comment: My goal is to have my table filtered with what is in "arrLstColorFilter" but noting is being filtered in the table. @rayryeng

Comment: How can `exp` be something like `09:19:19` when your substring call is out of bounds?  That string does not have a 12th position or a 20th position.  It has only 8 characters.  We are not a code writing service.  Please put more information in your problem, as well as example inputs and outputs.  You are making this harder than rocket science, and we are not clairvoyant.